# Enterprise Library Logging: TraceListeners Question

Tags: logging, enterprise-library, listeners

Is it possible to log certain events to -> event log for example, while others to -> file trace listener, while others still to -> SQL database.

I want to be able to configure this somewhere so errors go to text, verbose information goes to SQL, and warnings go to (event viewer and text).

Is this type of thing possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yes](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Log_Event_to_Listener_Routing_in_Enterprise_Library.aspx).